# Wort für "Hennedäpperle": Fortbewegung um eine Fußlänge

Tags: single-word-request, swabian

Von früher kenne ich das Kinderspiel "Kaiser wieviel Schritte gibst Du mir?", das wir oft im Garten gespielt haben. Der "Kaiser" bestimmt dabei eine Anzahl von Schritten, die ein Kind vorwärts gehen darf. Wer als erstes beim Kaiser ankommt, hat gewonnen und löst ihn ab.

Wenn man unter des Kaisers Mißgunst fiel, dann durfte man bei uns (Schwaben) nur wenige *[Hennedäpperle](http://norbertbaasner.de/woerterbuch/woerterbuch.php?buchst=h)* machen. Ein *Hennedäpperle* war die Bezeichnung für **das Fortbewegen um genau eine Fußlänge**, wenn man einen Fuß vor den anderen setzte. Meine Recherchen haben noch die wohl regional verschiedenen Alternativen *Mäuseschritt* oder *Katzendäpperle* gefunden, dies aber immer auf das Kinderspiel bezogen.

Jetzt suche ich einen nicht nur in Schwaben verständlichen, ähnlich knappen Begriff für die Fortbewegung um genau eine Fußlänge, den man auch außerhalb des Kinderspiel verwenden kann.

Comment: es ist keine richtige antwort, aber die bewegung als solche ist mir vom (kinder-)fußball als "tip-top" (zur seitenwahl etc.) bekannt

Comment: @Bort Zu meiner Zeit hieß das im Norden _Piss-Pott_ (also ‚Nachttopf‘).

Comment: Zur Frage: Man könnte analog zu _Schritt_ etwas wie _Fuß nach/für/auf Fuß_ bilden, aber ich weiß nicht, ob das irgendwo gebräuchlich ist (vgl. engl. _step-by-step_).

Answer (score 3):

Ein "Minischritt" wäre eine Möglichkeit. Das ist zwar nicht "genau eine Fußlänge", aber doch immerhin sowas wie der "kleinste denkbare" oder "kleinste sinnvoll machbare" Schritt.

Das Wort wird auch im übertragenen Sinn benutzt. Hier schwingt dann (meiner Erfahrung nach) oft eine Wertung mit, dass nämlich irgendeine (gewünschte) Veränderung zwar begonnen hat, aber noch lange nicht vollendet ist.

Comment: Willkommen im StackExchange für die Deutsche Sprache. Wenn Du magst, nimm die [tour] oder schau dich im [help] um. Viel Spaß!

Answer (score 3):

Ich kenne aus meiner Kindheit den Begriff "Kaffeebohne" für eine Fußlänge.

D.h., habe ich eine Entfernung in Kaffeebohnen abgemessen, dann habe ich Ferse an Fußspitze gesetzt und gezählt, wie oft das geht. Also wie viele Füße ich hintereinander setzen musste, um die Strecke zu schaffen.

Habe auf [dieser Seite](http://www.bewegte-schule-und-kita.de/konzept/bewegterKindergarten/deutsch/html/mathematische_bildung.html) ebenfalls diese Verwendung gefunden:

> Kinder im Vorschulalter messen mit Fußlängen (Kaffeebohnen) Gegenstände

PS: ich zweifel, dass es außerhalb von Kinderspielen einen anderen, "seriösen" Begriff als "Fuß" gibt (der in einigen Ländern auch "normiert lang" ist). Einfach weil in der Welt der Erwachsenen in Metern gemessen wird, denn "die sind ja klug". Außer so große Dinge wie Schritte, dies aber nur sehr begrenzt und situationsabhängig.

Comment: "Fußlänge" wäre ein knapper, passender Begriff

Answer (score 0):

Ein allgemein gebräuchlicher Begriff wäre neben der **Fußlänge** noch der **[Fußtritt](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=Fu%C3%9Ftritt)**. Zwar wird der Begriff heute hauptsächlich in der Bedeutung

> einen Fußtritt versetzen

gefunden, seltener auch in Zusammenhang mit dem Geräusch

> er hörte Fußtritte

Aber man kann durchaus auch heute noch die veraltete Bedeutung eines Schrittes in Fußlänge verstehen, wenn man dies mit einem entsprechenden Verb verknüpft:

> Er **machte einen Fußtritt** nach vorne.
>   Sie **ging** nur **einen Fußtritt** weiter.

Comment: Ich würde es nicht (richtig) verstehen …